# Two arrays, same length. If first array values equals true get values from second array

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays. They are always the same length. If `userEmotions[index]` value is true I need to add `userTimeData[index]` value to a variable:

```
var userEmotions = [false, true, false, true],
    userTimeData = [140, 320, 730, 50],
    userPercentage = 0;

// e.g add 320 and 50 to userPercentage:
// userPercentage == 370
```

How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: do you need just a single value or an array of values? what have you tried?

Comment: What about a simple for?

Comment: *"How do I go about achieving this?"* -- you take the third sentence from the text and turn it into code. As simple as: `for (index in userEmotions) { if (userEmotions[index]) { userPercentage += userTimeData[index]; } }`. Not enough to compute a percentage, but you can use it as a starting point.

Comment: `userPercentage = userEmotions.reduce((sum, e, i) => sum + (e && userTimeData[i]), 0)`

Comment: @NinaScholz an array of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for the first single value or zero as default value.

```js
var userEmotions = [false, true, true],
    userTimeData = [140, 320, 730],
    userPercentage = userTimeData[userEmotions.indexOf(true)] || 0;

console.log(userPercentage);
```

For getting an array of values, you could filter the values.

```js
var userEmotions = [false, true, true],
    userTimeData = [140, 320, 730],
    userPercentages = userTimeData.filter((_, i) => userEmotions[i]);

console.log(userPercentages);
```

Comment: Oh, I was just demonstrating that your code doesn't give the correct answer when the number of `true`s is not one.

Comment: @BuhBuh, the user wants to get a single value, and the first `true` value's index should be taken for the result, as the title of the post asks. what goes wrong with another `true` in the `userEmotions` array?

Comment: I see now you have interpenetrated the question differently.  I understood `first` to refer to the `first array`, where you took it to mean `first boolean`.  Maybe you are right.  The question is ambiguous.

Comment: Now that I read the question again, yes it is ambiguous and I meant first array. userPercentages.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0). Out of curiosity what does the (_, part in filter() do?

Comment: `_` is just a variable, which is not used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop:

```js
var userEmotions = [false, true, false],
  userTimeData = [140, 320, 730],
  userPercentage = 0;

for (i = 0; i < userEmotions.length; i++) { //loop the length of the array
  if (userEmotions[i]) { // check userEmotions is true
    userPercentage += userTimeData[i]; // if it is add userTimeData to percentage
  }
}

console.log(userPercentage);
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP wanted alternative approaches, so:

```js
userEmotions = [false, true, false],
userTimeData = [140, 320, 730],
userPercentage = userEmotions
    .map(x => x ? 1 : 0)
    .map((x, i) => x * userTimeData[i])
    .reduce((a,b) => a+b);

console.log(userPercentage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why over engineer it, a simple for loop solves your problem -

```js
var userEmotions = [false, true, false],
    userTimeData = [140, 320, 730],
    userPercentage = 0;

for (i = 0; i < userEmotions.length; i++) {
  if (userEmotions[i]) {
    userPercentage += userTimeData[i];
  }
}

console.log(userPercentage);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this :

```
for(let i = 0 ; i < userEmotions .length ; i++){
   if(userEmotions[i]){
       userPercentage = userTimeData[i]
   }
}
```

Let me know if it help you :)